# non linear model fit for a complex function

Tags: fitting, complex, nonlinear

I am trying to fit a complex function which is basically a function for anelastic relaxation. I have 3 columns in my dataset [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmYM_9lNsudPlF6caxsGT9DkDuf3Vvyw/view?usp=sharing)  , first column is the temperature (which I have denoted by x here), 2nd column is the real part and 3rd column is the imaginary part and 4 coloumn is w:

```
Data = Import["E:\\Shelender\\codes\\Mathematica\\Aelastic \
relaxation\\datat1.asc"];
real = Data[[All, {1, 2}]];
imag = Data[[All, {1, 3}]];
w = Data[[All, {4}]];
Model = (A*E^(d/x)*tw)/(-I + E^(d/x)*tw);
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0], ComplexExpand[ReIm@Model], 
Rationalize[{{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {t, 1.0*10^-12}, {d, 10}}, 0], {x}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 10];
fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

Here in the model, we have to include w for the corresponding value of x and I do not know how to proceed with it.

Here A is the elastic constant, d is energy, t is relaxation time, w is the resonance frequency which is given to us and x is the temperature.

Intial guess of A,d,t are {1e-4, 7, 1e-12}

Comment: Take a look at [MultiNonlinearModelFit](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit). If you write your model as the list `ComplexExpand[ReIm @ Model]`, you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: I am trying this but somehow it is not working please correct me,  fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][{real, 
     imag}, {ComplexExpand[ReIm@Model]}, {{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {w, 
      1.0*10^8}, {d, 10}}, {t, 1.0*10^-12}}, {x}]

Comment: 1: You're throwing away the x-axis. You should define `real` as `Data[[All, {1, 2}]]` (and similarly for `imag`). 2: `ComplexExpand[ReIm @ Model]` is already a list of two elements. Don't wrap another list around it. If you post your data (or at least part of it), I can actually try the fit and post an answer. You can use, e.g., `RandomSample[Data, 20]` to get a sample of the data you can post easily.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have modified the code , please have a look. I have already attached the data file with my question (it is called Data, link is available in 2nd line of the question)

Comment: You didn't make the data publicly available on Google Drive, so I can't see it.

Comment: sorry for that, I did not made it public by mistake, I have given you the acess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113573/discussion-between-shelender-kumar-and-sjoerd-smit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
real = Data[[All, {1, 2}]];
imag = Data[[All, {1, 3}]];
Model = (A*E^(d/x)*t*w)/(-I + E^(d/x)*t*w);
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
  {real, imag},
  ComplexExpand[ReIm@Model],
  {{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {w, 1.0*10^8}, {d, 10}, {t, 1.0*10^-12}}, {x}
]
```

It looks like this problem is better handled with higher precision, because it looks like it stalls out otherwise (ignore the message):

```
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
  Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0],
  ComplexExpand[ReIm@Model],
  Rationalize[
   {{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {w, 1.0*10^8}, {d, 10}, {t, 1.0*10^-12}},
   0
   ],
  {x},
  WorkingPrecision -> 30
]
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

Show the plots:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{real, imag}],
 Plot[{fit[1, x], fit[2, x]}, 
   {x, 0, Max[real[[All, 1]], imag[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All],
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

As you can see, the fit is quite poor. You probably need to find better starting values to get a good fit. Also: the variables `t` and `w` are ill-posed since only their product is involved in the model. There's no way they can be fitted individually, so you should remove one of them from the model and only fit their product:

```
Model = (A*E^(d/x)*tw)/(-I + E^(d/x)*tw);
fit = ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][
   Rationalize[{real, imag}, 0], ComplexExpand[ReIm@Model], 
   Rationalize[{{A, 1.0*10^-4}, {tw, 1.0*10^-4}, {d, 10}}, 0], {x}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Show[
  ListPlot[{real, imag}], 
  Plot[{fit[1, x], fit[2, x]}, {x, 0, Max[real[[All, 1]], imag[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All], 
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

> [image]

Still not fantastic, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried plotting the fits but I am getting empty plots, I tried the following, Plot[{fit[1, x], fit[2, x]}, {x, 0.2, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All]

Comment: I made a few typos and copy-paste mistakes. Sorry about that. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do not understand why I am not able to see the plot, I am getting : Format: Recursion depth limit and them it says formatting notebook content and then windows closes afterwards. Also when I am using WorkingPrecision -> 30, I am not able to fit , I am getting The precision of the data and model function (MachinePrecision) is \ less than the specified WorkingPrecision (30), but I am able to fit it without using WorkingPrecision -> 30, but plotting as you mentioned just closes my window, is it related to the shortage in memory.

Comment: It looks like the fit without `WorkingPrecision -> 30` looks roughly the same, so just try the last block of code I posted without that option. You can check if it's a memory issue by looking at your system resource monitor (e.g., TaskManager on Windows) and looking at the RAM graph while you run the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying to fit one more function which involves definite integral  (rest of the part is almost same as above function) ,I thought I might be able to solve it but I am getting an error as I am introducing definite integral, I am posting this one as another question as other might get the help of multinonlinear model function in future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that MultiNonlinearModelfir works with 12.0 v only and I am using version 10.4, Do you know any trick by which I can fit this complex function?

Comment: @ShelenderKumar Download the source notebook and copy the code into your own notebook. You can also see the source code [here](https://github.com/ssmit1986/FunctionRepositoryFunctions/blob/sjoerds/development/FunctionRepo/Kernel/MultiNonlinearModelFit.wl)

Comment: @Sjored Smit As you mentioned in the above model variables t and w are ill-posed, I have also values of w corresponding to x. Can we include that somehow in the above model?

Comment: @ShelenderKumar That question is too vague for me to answer. If you update the question, I might be able to take a look at it when I have the time.

Comment: @Sjored Smit I made some mistake so I updated the question again